# How to save pointers to interface methods?

Tags: delphi

I have next code. How to store pointers to functions Voice declared by the interface in an array? 
If the abstract class TAnimal is used instead of the IVoice interface, then the pointers to the Voice function are stored in the array successfully!

PS. Delphi 10.3 Rio

```pascal
type
  IVoice = interface
    function Voice: string;
  end;

  TAnimal = class abstract (TInterfacedObject)
  strict private
    FName: string;
  public
    property Name: string read FName write FName;
  end;

  TDog = class(TAnimal, IVoice)
  protected
    function Voice: string;
  end;

  TCat = class(TAnimal, IVoice)
  protected
    function Voice: string;
  end;

{ TDog }

function TDog.Voice: string;
begin
  Result:= 'Arf-Arf!';
end;

{ TCat }

function TCat.Voice: string;
begin
  Result:= 'Meow-Meow!';
end;

var
  voices: TArray<IVoice>;
  funcs: TArray<TFunc<string>>;
  I: Integer;

begin
  voices:= [TDog.Create, TCat.Create, TDog.Create];
  SetLength(funcs, Length(voices));

  for I := 0 to High(voices) do
    funcs[i]:= voices[i].Voice;  //<--- don't compile

  for I := 0 to High(funcs) do
    Writeln(funcs[i]());

  Readln;
end.
```

I expect the output

```
Arf-Arf!
Meow-Meow!
Arf-Arf!
```

but this code don't compile with error:
`E2010 Incompatible types: 'System.SysUtils.TFunc<System.string>' and 'string'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to manually wrap the call to the interface method in an anonymous method. Like this:

```
funcs[i]:=
  function: string
  begin
    Result := voices[i].Voice;
  end;
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you dude very much! I love anonymous functions, that is necessary! xD